# MySQL varchar size storage - one byte, two byte conversion

Tags: mysql, varchar

According to the MySQL documentation, `VARCHAR` will use 1 byte to denote the length of the string provided all values in that column are of length 0-255, and otherwise 2 bytes will be used.

What happens if you have large amounts of data in a column which are all 255 or less, and after  entries, a single entry of length 256 is entered. Does a re-format operation kick in to update the other strings in this column to use 2 bytes instead of 1? Is there a way to preempt this operation aside from inserting invalid/ignored data? Something like `myField VARCHAR(1000) not null always-use-two-bytes,` (obviously it would be cleaner than that... but you get the idea).

Comment: Any reason you're worried about this? If you don't want to allow 256+ bytes to be inserted,t hen make the field varchar(255) instead.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to allow 256+ or more to be inserted. What I don't want is having a table-wide operation coming in late into the table's lifetime, and also to understand how it handles that conversion. I understand the idea that typically, if something CAN handle more than 255, it probably will early into its lifetime. What I envision is a table populated by a static process that typically puts 100 in, but the table supports perhaps 400. Late in the lifetime of the app, the process decides to put more data in there, and now we have a large resize.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't think mysql would REDUCE the field size if all the values go below 2byte lengths, so you could always 'prime' the table by inserting a large value early on, then updating with the real value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual quote from the docs is:

> A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

What this means to me is that if you have varchar(256+) then it's going to use 2 bytes from the beginning.